# find time difference between previous and new data in collection using pymongo

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, list-comprehension, pymongo

I have list of dictionary data which is inserted in mongodb using pymongo

```
    data =[{
        "cam_name" : "cam1",
        "stats" : [
                {
                        "total" : 10,
                        "red" : 5,
                        "yellow" : 0,
                        "green" : 5,
                        "time_stamp" : datetime(2020,6,20,17,52,4,992000),
                        "image_path" : "image/19-06-2020/cam1/19-06-2020_17-52-16.jpg"
                },
                {
                        "total" : 10,
                        "red" : 5,
                        "yellow" : 0,
                        "green" : 5,
                        "time_stamp" : datetime(2020,6,20,17,52,27,992000),
                        "image_path" : "image/19-06-2020/cam1/19-06-2020_17-52-25.jpg"
                },
                {
                        "total" : 10,
                        "red" : 5,
                        "yellow" : 0,
                        "green" : 5,
                        "time_stamp" : datetime(2020,6,20,17,52,1,992000),
                        "image_path" : "image/19-06-2020/cam1/19-06-2020_17-52-25.jpg"
                }]
},

    {
        "cam_name": "cam2",
        "stats": [
            {
                "total": 10,
                "red": 5,
                "yellow": 0,
                "green": 5,
                "time_stamp": datetime(2020, 6, 20, 17, 52, 6, 992000),
                "image_path": "image/19-06-2020/cam1/19-06-2020_17-52-16.jpg"
            },
            {
                "total": 10,
                "red": 5,
                "yellow": 0,
                "green": 5,
                "time_stamp": datetime(2020, 6, 20, 17, 52, 59, 992000),
                "image_path": "image/19-06-2020/cam1/19-06-2020_17-52-25.jpg"
            },
            {
                "total": 10,
                "red": 5,
                "yellow": 0,
                "green": 5,
                "time_stamp": datetime(2020,6, 20, 17, 52, 4, 992000),
                "image_path": "image/19-06-2020/cam1/19-06-2020_17-52-25.jpg"
            }]
    }

]
```

And after entering the data I am trying to find the difference between time between each element in list of dictionaries available for key ['stats']['time_stamp']

But I am not able to find out by using the approach of finding  difference between the elements available in the list

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime
import json
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

myclient = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)

master_data = myclient['data_set']
cam_db = master_data['cam_table']

prev = None
for i,c in enumerate(data):
for k in c['stats']:
    #print(k['time_stamp'])
    if prev==None:
        prev = k['time_stamp']
        #print(prev)
    else:
        prev = k['time_stamp'] - prev
        print(prev)
```

output:

```
0:00:23
2020-06-20 17:52:08.992000
-1 day, 23:59:56
2020-06-20 17:52:31.992000
0:00:00
```

after that, I am not able to find the perfect approach to use for find out the time difference

Note: I want to check whether time difference between every data available is less than 20 seconds or not
Suggestions will be really helpful

Comment: What will be the expected output ?

Comment: @Sushanth Expected output is giving all the dates but the ones which i need

Comment: what is that your expecting, can u be more explicit ?

Comment: added a note in question

Comment: So you want to iterate `stats` array/dictionary, calculate the elapsed time from each sample and the one before, and return true if any of these intervals is greater than 20 seconds, false otherwise?

Comment: yes @Joe you got me

Comment: Have you tried using a variable to hold the last time seen, and updating after each element in the stats array?

Comment: i tried in that way but got weird results updated in question